# Using Python to generate exports for .bashrc

Tags: python, bash, path, environment-variables

When I manually build and install projects they are installed into `$HOME/.prefix/<project>`

Having each project in it's own folder makes it easier to remove later. Right now I have to manually add each project to `PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, C_INCLUDE, and CPLUS_INCLUDE`. I would like to automate this using Python, but I'm running into issues. If I use Python's `os.environ` then the settings don't persist. I also tried outputting a single command to `stdout` which is run by `.bashrc` like this: `$(python scan.py)`. This failed, with the following as an example:

After reloading my `.bashrc` my `PATH` variable was literally: `$HOME/.prefix/clang/bin:$PATH`. The problem is that last `$PATH`, it should have been expanded to include everything that `PATH` contained previously.

Comment: We need to see your code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your python script is outputting a string that has $HOME and $PATH in it. bash is not expanding those variables because they are not actually in your bash script.

- You could write your python script to get the HOME and PATH environment variables and just output paths, rather than expecting the shell to expand them
- You could pass them to your script as command-line arguments
- You *could* `eval` the output in bash but `eval` is not necessarily a great habit